# safari a:visited border color automatically on div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div wrapped in a `<a>` tag like this...

```
<a href='/'><span>Quiz</span>
```

and then my css stylesheet looks like this...

```
a:visited {
    color: green;
}
```

But when the link is visited, it looks like this...

[image]

I have tried defining the border settings in the `a` css selector in various ways with no luck. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think the weird behavior comes from the fact that you're embedding a block element inside a div element.  They should be the other way around.

Comment: do you mean a block element inside of an anchor?

Comment: I meant block element inside an inline element, sorry.

Comment: But yes - specifically the anchor tag.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, I made a mistake. The element inside of the anchor is a span, not a div....So it is not a block element, right? Does this change tour view?

Comment: Basically your code is wrong, you have an extra `</div>` in there...

Comment: @xpy that was a type on my part, I initially wrote div when it was actually a span and then typo'd it when I tried to correct it

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You say "It looks like this" but you don't say how it is supposed to look like. Also, posting all the relevant `CSS` Would be helpful.

Comment: I thought I did post the relevant css lines? I would like it to change the color of the font, but not add an outline on the `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an outline, probably there is already a `border` on, either your `span` or your `a`. Now, if the border doesn't have a specific color set, e.g.

```
border: 1px solid;
```

instead of

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

then it's color is defined by the `color` property. Which means that what is happening is normal.

Now, you have two options, either you find where is this border defined and remove it or add a color to it. Or you override it in some way like:

```
a:visited {
  color: green;
  border-color:transparent;
}
```

you may need `!important` on the `border-color` rule but that depends.

Answer (score 0):

Use `outline` instead of `border` to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: and what do I add to outline..I tried `outline:none;` and that didn't work for me

Comment: a, a:visited, a:focus{outline:0 none;}

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be better if you look into the style section of the safari inspection. There are certain browser default styles which behave in a similar way. If you find any `outline` or `border` declaration, try to neutralize that declaration by declaring from your end `border: 0; outline: none;`

It will be of real help if you could share with us the code over **fiddle** or **codepen**.

**Note:** I was unable to recreate the scenario as you specified.